# How to write from an excel sheet into a table in an already created word doc

Tags: excel, python-3.x, ms-word

Relatively new to python. looking for a way to write from an excel sheet into a **table** (in an already created and formatted) word doc. Currently, I have following code that can read from the excel file and write into the word doc but it only writes as a new paragraph in the word doc. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
import openpyxl
from docx import Document

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('filename.xlsx', data_only=True)
file= wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')


doc = Document('blankdoc.docx')
for i in range(10, 34):
    doc.add_paragraph(file['B' + str(i)].value)

doc.save('blankdoc.docx')
```

Comment: Please add the code that you already have done.

Comment: I understand there is a _table function in the docx module but im still unsure how to use it.